# rsync in crontab job fails, but if command is ran manually succeeds

Tags: cron, rsync

I am running the following command in my backup script:

```
rsync -ravv root@serverprod:/home/user/sites/main_site/backup/*.zip /space/backup/main_site/
```

crontab -e as root:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
*       20      *       *       1-5     python /root/scripts/backup/backup.py -S -F main_site
```

I run into a issue every time `rsync` runs in `crontab`, but if I try to run it manually, it succeeds.

Error:

```
rsync: mkstemp "/space/backup/main_site/.main_site_2016_01_29_132442250748_a82abb7e57f88c2afedb2e00c022f935c470b9e1_backup.zip.I3kVYl" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

I get this error for all of the files I am fetching from my source folder.

Now have in mind that `main_site_2016_01_29_132442250748_a82abb7e57f88c2afedb2e00c022f935c470b9e1_backup.zip` is an expected file name. However, what comes before it, `.` and after `.I3kVYl` are not. I guess this must be temporary files the command creates in order to perform its operations. And the question is: why this error?

I am using Ubuntu server 14.04.5.

Comment: How do you authenticate?

Comment: @Jakuje It's a SSH-key.

Comment: And where is it? How are you giving it to the `rsync` under different user?

Comment: @Jakuje The user making the login is also root. I have corrected that information.